# I am using tkinter and openpyexcel and there is/ are bugs in my code which i am unable to identify. please help me

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I am making a password generator which requires me to enter the length of the password and the website for which i am saving that password. the password and website name are stored in an excel sheet. so in this project i am using tkinter and openpyexcel. when i run the code everything goes well, i enter the website name, the length of the password and the password is generated. but when is open the spreadsheet, the password and website name is not saved there. here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip
import random
import openpyexcel as xl


root = Tk()


label2 = Label(text='enter the website name')
label2.pack()

entryForWebsiteName = tk.Entry(root)
entryForWebsiteName.pack()

websiteName = entryForWebsiteName.get()

workbook = xl.load_workbook('password_database.xlsx')
sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 1)
    if cell.value == None:
        cell.value = websiteName
    else:
        pass


label1 = Label(text='enter the number of characters in your password: ')
label1.pack()


entryForNumOfChar = tk.Entry(root)

entryForNumOfChar.pack()
def password_generator():
    chars = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]\;/.'

    n_of_chars = int(entryForNumOfChar.get())

    password = ''
    for x in range(0, n_of_chars):
        char = random.choice(chars)
        password = password + char
    
    label1 = Label(text=password)
    label1.pack()
    pyperclip.copy(password)

    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, 2)
        if cell.value == None:
            cell.value = password

        else:
            pass
    
    workbook.save('password_database.xlsx')

generatePasswordButton = Button(text='click to generate password', command=password_generator)
generatePasswordButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

can u please tell me what is going wrong and the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the sheet have a header?

If it does you should use this.

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 2):
```

This code will save the website and password.

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 2):
  
  cell = sheet.cell(row, 1)
  if cell.value == None:
     cell.value = entryForWebsiteName.get()
     cell.offset(0,1).value = password
  else:
     pass
```